# why is my code not letting me call the var Diceroll?

Tags: c#, .net

in VSC first i tried to return the variable `uint PlayersDiceRoll` but i kept getting a error about not being able to put `Random.Next()` in a static method or something like that, so i changed it and tried to call the method as a whole and am now getting a error saying the variable `DiceRoll` isnt in my code, so someone please help me.

```
  using System;

namespace _Test_simplyVideoGame
{
    //Change class name to video game title when it is known.
    class Program
    {

        public void Main(string[] args)
        {
           PlayerDiceRoll(DiceRoll);
           

        }

        public uint PlayerDiceRoll(uint DiceRoll)
        {
            Random Dice = new Random();
            uint PlayersDiceRoll = Convert.ToUInt32(Random.Next)(uint.MinValue,uint.MaxValue);
            return DiceRoll;




        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (1) From what I can see the problem you're describing is that you need to change `Convert.ToUInt32(Random.Next)(uint.MinValue,uint.MaxValue);` to `Dice.Next(uint.MinValue,uint.MaxValue);`. You were attempting to access a static method named `Next` on the `Random` class, but that method isn't static you need to invoke it on an object of type `Random`, in this case `Dice`.

Comment: You changed `PlayerDiceRoll` as you described to return `DiceRoll`, but in doing so you're now returning the input parameter as the output of the method making the rest of the code in the method redundant. You should change that `return DiceRoll;` back to `return PlayersDiceRoll;`

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of the `DiceRoll` parameter in the `PlayerDiceRoll` function is because it's never used in the function. I assume you want this to be the maximum number the random object can return, in which case you should further change it to `Dice.Next(uint.MinValue, DiceRoll);`

Answer (score 0):

Start by making your functions static
actually use the Random object
and if you only want positive random number I would just use int from 0 to max which is 2b values, if you need 4b possible options you could go from negative to possitive and then add the possitive, but you must make sure not to exceed the bounds of uint

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var playerRolled = PlayerDiceRoll();
        Console.WriteLine("Player rolled: " + playerRolled);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static int PlayerDiceRoll()
    {
        Random Dice = new Random();
        var randomValue = Dice.Next(0, int.MaxValue);
        return randomValue;

    }
```

And just for a bit of fun:
You could make general dice if you need it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        var playerRolled = PlayerDiceRoll();
        Console.WriteLine("Player rolled: " + playerRolled);
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Player rolls default die: " + PlayerRoleSidedDie(6));
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Player rolls 64 value die die with 16 sides : " + PlayerRoleSidedDie(16,4));
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Player rolls two 6 sided dice");
        var die1 = PlayerRoleSidedDie(6);
        var die2 = PlayerRoleSidedDie(6);
        Console.WriteLine("die 1 was: " + die1 + " die 2 was: " + die2 + " total roll was: " + (die1 + die2));
            Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static int PlayerDiceRoll()
    {
        Random Dice = new Random();
        var randomValue = Dice.Next(0, int.MaxValue);
        return randomValue;

    }
    public static int PlayerRoleSidedDie(int size, int multiplyer=1)
    {
        Random die = new Random();
        var selectedSide = die.Next(1, size);
        return selectedSide * multiplyer;
    }
}
```